# ResourceClosedError/AttributeError when using pandas read_sql_query AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read a sql query using pandas.read_sql_query.

The issues I have were not here a few weeks ago. The issue is when I read some queries, I get the following errors:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql = query_string, con = engine)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py in _fetchall_impl(self)
   1160         try:
-> 1161             return self.cursor.fetchall()
   1162         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ResourceClosedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
...
~\.conda\envs\test\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py in _non_result(self, default)
   1166         if self._metadata is None:
   1167             raise exc.ResourceClosedError(
-> 1168                 "This result object does not return rows. "
   1169                 "It has been closed automatically."
   1170             )

ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

This only happens when using some queries and not others so I know it's not my connection. I have SET NOCOUNT ON on both statements and both are using temp tables. Can anyone guide me as to why one query is working and not the other? Both work in SSMS fine. I have tried to provide the basic structure of both below. First one works, second does not work.

```
set nocount on
                                                                    
DECLARE      @var1  varchar(20)= 'sometext'                                                             
                                                                
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1', 'U') IS NOT NULL                                                                     
        DROP TABLE #temp1                                                                       
                                                                        
select * into  #temp1 from  some_function_view WHERE  [x] = @var1                                                                       
                                                                        
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2', 'U') IS NOT NULL                                                                     
        DROP TABLE #temp2                                                                       
select * into #temp2 FROM another_view JOIN ...                                                     
                                                                        
SELECT Main.[y]...                                                                                                                                      
FROM (                                                                      
                                                                        
    SELECT *                                                                                                                                    
    FROM another_view                                                                       
    JOIN...                                                                                                                                     
    WHERE...                                                                
    GROUP BY...
) Main                                                                      
    JOIN #temp2...
```

```
set nocount on

begin try drop table #temp1 end try begin catch end catch
begin try drop table #temp2 end try begin catch end catch
begin try drop table #temp3 end try begin catch end catch

DECLARE @x  int = 202007
DECLARE @y  int = 2016  

SELECT * into #temp1 FROM a_view

SELECT  * into #temp2       
FROM a_view     
JOIN (SELECT...FROM a_view WHERE...GROUP BY ...)


SELECT... into #temp3 FROM a_view       
JOIN... 
LEFT JOIN...
WHERE x = @x, y = @y... 
Group BY...

SELECT *

FROM #policy as FPFR        
    JOIN #temp1...
    JOIN #temp2...
    JOIN #temp3...
ORDER BY...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I needed to include "SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF" ***and*** "SET NOCOUNT ON" in my SQL query.

Having one or the other was not enough. The combination of both manages to catch any stored procedure errors thrown out by the SQL so that Python can read it successfully.